# Rewrite rules causing hole

Tags: custom-post-types, rewrite-rules, custom-post-type-archives

I am using rewrite rules to catch /events/date/*

Events is the custom post type I am working with. So archive-events.php, is normally my index, but with my rewrite rules, I need to identify a specific pagename. Do I have to duplicate that specific file, or is there a way I can point to archives-events.php?  see below...

```
function add_events_rewrite_rules($aRules) {
    $aNewRules = array('events/date/([^/]+)/?$' => 'index.php?pagename=events&_events_date=$matches[1]');
    $aRules = $aNewRules + $aRules;
    return $aRules;
}
add_filter('rewrite_rules_array', 'add_events_rewrite_rules');
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to specify a pagename, if you want to replicate a post type archive set `post_type` instead.

```
function add_events_rewrite_rules(){
    add_rewrite_rule(
        'events/date/([^/]+)/?$',
        'index.php?post_type=events&_events_date=$matches[1]',
        'top'
    );
}
add_action( 'init', 'add_events_rewrite_rules' );
```